# LAS .PTC classes into ESRI LAS to Mulitpoint

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, las, microstation

We have some Lidar data that has been classified based on visable features (i.e. trees, streets, buildings, etc.) These LAS data are used inside inside Microstation w/ TerraScan connected to a PTC file.

PTC file resembles this; 
0       Unclassified
*   Zero length line    9   0   0
1       Unknown
*   Zero length line    9   0   0
2       Bare Earth
*   Zero length line    2   50  0

Is there a way to use this PTC file when symbolizing the resulting ESRI point cloud (ArcScene) following the LAS to Multipoint conversion. All the points are showing, but need to find out how to use the FC in the symbology inside ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right a PTC file is a list of classifications and their codes.  It has been a while since I've used terrascan.

Once you add the las dataset to arcmap - right click properties - symbology - add  -las attribute grouped with unique symbol.  This then lists the classes in the lidar file and you can color however you want.

[image]

Comment: We are using 10.1, What version of ESRI is that? Also how are you loading a LAS files directly without going through the conversion from LAS to Mulitpoint? Do you have some plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 10.2.  But you can do the same in 10.1  I just created a LAS dataset. It's under Data Management.

[image]

Comment: I've tried that however due to the customization of our LAS classes ESRI does not perform 1 to 1 input to output.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the LAS codes in 3D Analyst - Data Management - LAS Dataset. And then remap them to whatever you want.